# PHP - Weird session variable behaviour

Tags: php, session

I have a website that I developed using PHP 5.6.11 that I'm trying to deploy on a web host that uses 5.3.29, and unfortunately I'm running into some issues. In my local environment everything works as intended, but on the web server I'm having trouble with being unable to change the value of session variables. I made some simple test scripts that reproduce the problem:

testmain.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text">
        <button onclick="callTest1();">button1</button>
        <button onclick="callTest2();">button2</button>

        <script>
            function callTest1() {
                var text = $("input").val();
                $.get("test1.php?text="+text);
            }

            function callTest2() {
                $.get("test2.php");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['testVar'] = $_GET['text'];
echo $_SESSION['testVar'];
```

test2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['testVar'];
```

The problem here is with `test2.php`. It always has the same value for `$_SESSION['testVar']` regardless of how many times I call `test1.php` to change it. Here's a scenario that shows the problem pretty well:

1. I type '455' into the textfield and click button1. `test1.php` echoes back '455'.
2. I click button2. `test2.php` echoes back '455'.
3. I type '324' into the textfield and click button1. `test1.php` echoes back '324'.
4. I click button2. `test2.php` echoes back '455'. I expected '324'.

And now `test2.php` will have '455' as it's value for `$_SESSION['testVar']` the entire session and I cannot change it. Does anyone know what the heck is happening here?

Comment: Sorry, not able to reproduce on php 5.3.2 ~ works as expected

Comment: Is it a shared host?, because some shared hosts do stupid shit with sessions.

Comment: Might be a good idea to contact them about it then